# Export from Excel to PDF change in margins

Tags: excel, pdf, margins

Whenever exporting from Excel to PDF (via Microsoft print to pdf) the resulting pdf file would have different margins from the original shown in Excel print preview. The margins are wider and the size of the page is changed from A4 (as in the Excel file) to Letter. Is there a way to fix this please? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of 'Microsoft Print to PDF' I would recommend using 'Save As', then in the dropdown 'Save as type:' you can chose 'PDF'.  This then saves a PDF that (for me) matches the presentation I expect.

Alternatively, if you do want to use 'Microsoft Print to PDF' you could try to go to printer properties (for 'Microsoft Print to PDF'), then select 'Advanced', then check that the 'paper size' dropdown is set to A4.

Comment: Using 'Save As' solved the problem. Thanks